# Usar variable en etiqueta de imagen src JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, web, src

Quisiera saber si es posible usar una variable como el nombre de una imagen, por ejemplo, e estado intentando lo siguiente pero no me aparecen las imágenes en pantalla.

```
        var table = "<table><tr><td>Cantidad</td><td>" + copia.toString() +"</td></tr>";
        for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++){
            if(cantidad[i] != 0)
                table +="<tr><td>" +  "<img src='"+i+".jpg' />" + "</td><td>" + moneda[i] + "</td><td>" + cantidad[i] + "</td></tr>";
        }
        table+="</table>";
        document.getElementById('resultado').innerHTML = table;
```

Comment: Cuál es la ruta de las imágenes y del HTML que las muestra?

Comment: Como te dice el usuario de arriba, ¿las imágenes las tienes en la misma carpeta que el archivo que estás ejecutando? Si no es así, tienes que poner la ruta antes del nombre de la imagen.

Comment: Lo que estás intentado hacer esta bien, podrías indicar el erro que te sale?